# express node how to avoid sending user data on every request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i was wandering what is the best way to avoid sending the user data on every request,
lets say i want to add product from user's account, i have to send the user. or i want to order something, i have to send the user.
i thought about something like this:

```html
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.userId) {
    return next();
  }
  const user = await enteties.User.findByPk(req.body.userId);
  req.user = user;
  next();
});
```

but it also requires me to send the user on evey request..

there must be a way to avoid sending the user data to the server on almost every request.
also, it will make all my requests of type "post" since i have to send the user, and even "get" requests are now become "posts", for sure this is not correct

Comment: You can use some authorization mechanism instead of sending the user detail on every request.

Comment: yeah i have authorization but then the after the request end the data of the user is gone from the server

Comment: If I am a user with id=100 and I request info for some other random user with id=333 how do you prevent me from seeing info I'm not supposed to be seeing? I mean, I can just send `userId=333` and spy on others. How do you protect user privacy?

Comment: You need to use sessions to access user data after the initial authentication.

Comment: you will have to authenticate to get to some routes @slebetman

Comment: @YakkoMajuri i thought no one uses sessions anymore

Comment: Are you using Passport? Check out their docs about serialization http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Comment: @YakkoMajuri im using jsonwebtoken do you think passport is better?

Comment: @gdsdasgga Sessions are still used. The only difference is weather it is stored at the client side or server side. Client-side session stores minimal data (usually user id or email and maybe some role info) in a signed token. The proof that you are who you say you are and can do what you want to do (roles etc.) is verified by verifying the signature. Check out JWT tokens for this. From what you say it looks like you know about server-side sessions. So I also assume you already know the answer though you may not realize it: you need a session mechanism

Comment: Said above very well. You need sessions. How you build that is up to you. I'm suggesting Passport for your whole authentication workflow, not just sessions, just because it's quite easy to use and well-established. But do as you wish.

Comment: @gdsdasgga Your JWT token should store your user identifier (either user id or email) typically in the `sub` attribute. You don't need to send additional user id on top of it. Your JWT token is the session. The signature prevents tampering with the session data

Comment: FYI, Passport has a JWT module if you need to use JWT along with complicated authentication mechanisms like OAuth or google or Facebook or linked-in etc.

Comment: @slebetman i guess i was talking about client session (which replaced by local storage)  and ye im using jwt for authentication, you say i should use server side session?

Comment: No, I'm saying that your token should already contain user id. If it does not you're using it wrong

Comment: @slebetman wait if i have jwt, i dont need session (i can achive it with jwt configs)???

Comment: What JWT library are you using?

Comment: @slebetman jsonwebtoken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implement your JWT token correctly you don't need to send the logged in user id.

JWT tokens contain a payload section that is basically any JSON data you want to set. This is basically your decentralized session stored in the user's machine. When creating a JWT token you'd normally do something like:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('./config');

function generateToken(user) {
    let payload = {
        sub: user.id
    };

    return jwt.sign(payload, config.secret, {
        algorithm: 'HS512', // choose algorithm appropriate for you
        expiresIn: config.expires
    })
}
```

That payload part allows you to send user identifying information. In the case above, the user id. To get that id from a request simply verify it:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.get('Authorization');
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, payload) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }
        else {
            req.user = payload; // user.sub is the user id
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Or you can use a library such as [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) to do it for you:

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./config');

const app = express();

app.use(expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }); // use express-jwt like any
                                        // middleware, you can even install
                                        // it on specific routes.
```

Now in your controller/route you can simply extract the payload in the `req.user` object. Invalid tokens or requests without tokens will completely skip your handler and immediately return an error or unauthorized response:

```
app.get('/some/endpoint', (req, res) => {

    console.log('user is', req.user.sub); // note: req.user is our payload

});
```

---

#### Additional tricks:

As I mentioned, the payload is basically user defined. If you need to keep track of other user information such as roles or permissions you can store them in the JWT token:

```
// Example payload
let payload = {
    sub: user.id,
    admin: user.role === 'admin',
    gender: user.gender
};
```

This reduces the number of database requests needed to process the user. Making the authentication system completely decentralized. For example you may have a service that consumes this JWT token that is not connected to your user database but need to check if user is admin. With the right payload that service does not even need to have access to the user database.

Note however that the payload is not encrypted. It is just base64 encoded. This means that the information in the token can be easily read by anyone with access to it (normally the user but beware of 3rd party scripts). So ideally you shouldn't store dox-able information in the payload if you have 3rd party scripts on your website (then again, it is highly unusual these days for anyone to write the entire front-end from scratch without any libraries or frameworks)

Also note that the more you put in your payload the larger your token will be.

Comment: thanks a lot man, i understand much better now!  a little question,  i should send the token from the client to the server through headers right?

Comment: That's up to you. Two popular choices is via the Authorization header (this is partly standardized but not directly supported by the browser - you need to handle it yourself in js) and also via cookies - simply store the entire token as a cookie (this is kind of non-standard but has 100% browser support without additional js coding)